# Render component inside .map onClick() - React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, indexing

I'm trying to render component onClick and the problem I faced is that my onClick opens component in every row not only in the one I clicked button.
It's probably any index issue. Could you take a look at my code? Thanks!

```
 class ItemView extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      isFormOpen: false,
      parentId: null,
    }
  }

  handleAddItem = (value) => {
    this.setState({
      parentId: value.parentId,
      isFormOpen: !this.state.isFormOpen,
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="ui relaxed divided list">
        {data.items.map((item, index) => {
          return (
            <div className="item" key={index}>
              <Button
                label={'Add Item'}
                onClick={() => this.handleAddItem({ parentId: item.parentId })}
              />
              {isFormOpen && (
                <AddItem parentId={parentId} />
              )}
            </div>
          )
        })}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Can we see your `data.items` object that you are iterating through?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add check if `parentId` is equal to `item.parentId`:

```
{isFormOpen && parentId === item.parentId && (
    <AddItem parentId={parentId} />
)}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are right.
For this you have to use Other Component. In this component because you are using `map` to render the element so it renders it in every time or row.
That's why when `isFormOpen` will be `true` so it'll be true on all items/rows.

Please use other component to render the conditional element.